# Enum indexes from string

Tags: vb.net, enums, console-application

Say I have a console app with the following code:

```
Enum FoodItems

   apple
   banana
   pineapple

End Enum

Sub Main()

   Dim input As String = Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

I want to be able to get a value from a particular member in *FoodItems* if *input* has the same value as a name of a member from the enum; ie get 1 when input is "banana". How could this be done working off this code?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know if I understood so well: you want the user to write something, if this something is a word in your Enum, the output will be the "number of the word in the Enum"? For example, if I write banana, the application will write 1.
If this is what you want you can easily do it like this:

```
If input = FoodItems.banana.ToString() Then Console.WriteLine(FoodItems.banana)
    Console.ReadLine()
```

If you want to check for all the elements in the Enum you have to Select Case:

```
    Sub Main()
    Dim input As String = Console.ReadLine()
    Select Case input
        Case FoodItems.apple.ToString()
            Console.WriteLine(FoodItems.apple)
        Case FoodItems.banana.ToString()
            Console.WriteLine(FoodItems.banana)
        Case FoodItems.pineapple.ToString()
            Console.WriteLine(FoodItems.pineapple)
    End Select
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Probably there is a better way to do it, but I would do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this - It worked fine for me. The function below either returns the enum index if the string is an enum, or returns -1 if not.

```
<Flags> Friend Enum test
    banana
    apple
    orange
    pear
End Enum

Private Function ReturnEnum(inputString As String) As Integer
    Dim a As test
    Try
        a = test.Parse(GetType(test), inputString)
    Catch
        Return -1
    End Try
    Return CInt(a)
End Function
```